# Coming soon pages - best practices?

Tags: social-media, email, input-fields

I think the design of these pages vary greatly, and there is no set standard on what's usually on these pages. However, one thing that has been common with these pages in the past is that people tend to include an input field allowing a user to sign up for notifications of the product launch. To me this screams, "We won’t tell you anything about our product, but we do want your email address." Does anyone else think the email sign ups on coming soon pages are cheesy and effective at getting people to sign up? There has been times I've signed up, and never received an email from the company about their launch.

To me I'd rather see a coming soon page that has creativity behind it with good design, the company branding (logo, color palette), and maybe even some screenshots of the soon to be product, as well as some well written copy or headlines about the product. Possibly some social media links, or the ability to share the page on my social media networks.

It also seems as though adding in these sign up processes and invitation systems are time consuming on development when you are already trying to develop your product for launch. Especially when you only plan to use this system one time... for your coming soon page.

Does anyone feel the same as me or am I being overly sensitive to the email issue? Are there any other 'must haves' to include on these pages that I didn't mention?

Comment: Under construction gif? ;) http://www.squidoo.com/under-construction-gif

Comment: This will be helpful http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/22963/how-can-i-represent-under-construction-pages-usefully

Comment: @sree Thanks, but that was only somewhat helpful. I'm aware of what typically goes on 'coming soon' pages; in fact nearly everything that was in that thread is what I already expressed above. I suppose my post was geared more towards whether or not adding a 'get notified email input area' was really worth the extra development (and if users actually interact with that element), and if there were any other ideas beyond what I mentioned that would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a user really wants to hear more about the product/service as soon as it becomes available, so having the data capture is fine... as long as you plan to actually fulfill the requests. You're right, having a data capture with no actual plans to give users updates is downright criminal. Furthermore, don't just wait until the site/product/service launches, let people know how it's coming along. They gave you their information for a reason.

Now, about some other options, something I think works really well is rather than just showing a logo with some information about the product/service, have a video with a key figure at the company explaining what the product is, why it's great and why we should care. It's not only more informative than a simple logo, but it allows users to put a face to the product. It makes the whole thing seem more "real". For a perfect example of this, check out some of the more recent and popular Kickstarters. The better ones use a mix of humor and information. When you think about it, these Kickstarter campaigns were basically "Coming Soon" pages with a twist. (Both links are completed Kickstarters and I'm in no way endorsing them).

Twilight Zone Pinball
http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1067367405/pinball-arcade-the-twilight-zone?ref=live

Double Fine Adventure Game
http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/doublefine/double-fine-adventure?ref=most-funded